# Proof dealing with greatest common divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm working on a proof which concludes that if $a\equiv b (mod\ m)$

then $gcd(a,m) = gcd(b,m)$

I know that we can rewrite the congruence as $km = a-b$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

I rearranged the equation to : $a = b + km$

So I have that:
$$gcd(b,m)|(b+km)$$
and
$$gcd(b,m)|a$$

I'm not sure where I'm supposed to go from here. I've been told that I can say that $$gcd(b,m) \leq gcd(a,m)$$ but I'm not sure how to draw that conclusion. Could someone explain that part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,d\mid m\,$ then $\,d\mid b\!+\!km\iff d\mid b.\,$ This implies that $\,m,\, b\!+\!km\,$ and $\,m,b\,$ have the same set $\,D\,$ of *common* divisors $\,d,\,$ thus they have the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max D)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Frequently, a good way to show that two positive integers are equal is to show that each is less than or equal to the other.  Here is a sketch, see if you can supply the reasons and then complete the proof.

1. Let $g=\gcd(a,m)$.  By definition, $g\mid a$ and $g\mid m$.
2. Then $g\mid b$, because...
3. So $g\le\gcd(b,m)$ because...
4. And can you now see what you still need to do?

Comment: $g|b$ because $g|a-km=b$ 
But I'm still having trouble understanding (3). Any other tips?

Comment: Oh wait, is it because if $g > gcd(b,m)$ then we have a contradiction because $gcd(b,m)$ is no longer the gcd?

Comment: Yes, even better with emphasis: $\gcd(b,m)$ would not be the **greatest** common divisor.